# Button display dependant on parent window

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage that can be accessed from 2 different areas, one navigates to the page and one opens a new window to the page. I'm trying to use the window.parent.location as a switch
to display either a "Back" for the navigated page or a "Close" for the new window.

Am I on the right path here, is there an easier way to do this?

All help appreciated

Comment: Could use a query-string parameter `?button=close` or a fragment identifier `#close` as part of the url to distinguish between the two. It might make more sense in general to use a modal to load the information, as pop-up windows are generally discouraged, but I don't know what your use case is.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(window.opener)
{
 ///show close
}
else
{
 ////    show back
}
```

Comment: @Frankie G if this solution worked for you, please take the time to "accept" it. This would be the tick mark under the upvote/downvote window. Thank you :)